# How to create a database schema which can hold info about the order and its items

Tags: database, database-design, datatable, database-schema

I am developing a web application. The user with a very simple operation has to select some items or products, in my case choose a food from a menu for example (Drink, Chips plate, Hamburger, Rice).

The problem is in the admin dash board I want to list the orders for the restaurant employers, each order combined with its items.

[image]

My question is what is the table schema I need in order to get my requests.

- productsTbl
- ordersTbl

Are my wanted food (my products) must have the same order id and how I can plan my tables.

When a user click checkout the order it self enter the order table with specific ID, i have to get this Id and give it to the products (wanted food)?

I hope I was clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at this:

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/generic_pos/index.htm

(I googled it - please try it sometime)

Based on your screenshot, you'd want three tables

First a list of all possible food that can be ordered:

```
Food
==============
FoodId (unique key)
FoodName
Price
```

Containing data like this:

```
FoodId    FoodName    Price
=============================
1         Hamburger   10
2         Rice        2
3         Chips       4
4         Drink       1
```

Then a table that describes a single order:

```
FoodOrder
==============
OrderId (unique key)
Status
Customer
OrderDate
```

If you had two orders being prepared and you had a bunch of paid ones from yesterday  it would look like this:

```
OrderId     Status     Customer     OrderDate
=================================================
114         Preparing  Jim          5/02/2020
113         Preparing  Jo           5/02/2020
112         Paid       Jill         4/02/2020
111         Paid       Jack         4/02/2020
```

Then a table that tells you, from the list of all possible food, what is on the order:

```
FoodOrderDetail
========
OrderId
FoodId
Price
```

(you might want store the price in this table as well, in case you want to apply a discount or if the price changes over time)

This is where food is attached to the orders

```
OrderId FoodId  Price
======================
113     1       10
113     2       2
113     4       1
114     2       2
114     4       1
```

But there are many additional complexities to consider to come up with the data model